# Oxford book template (Choquet-Bruhat, Maggiore, Simon,...)

Tags: book-design

I love the style of the book on general relativity by Choquet-Bruhat. I think it's the same as Maggiore's book on qft and Simon's on solid state physics.

I was wondering if this book design template or class is publicly available or if it is "property" of oxford university press. In the latter case, is there something close to it that I could find?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As someone who is connected to the Department of Physics at the relevant university, I can alas tell you that it isn't explicitly public domain. I too think it's great, and would love it to be more freely available. Entirely unofficially I know that it's the pet child of several academics, who have extended it quite thoroughly, and the press were quite surprised at how much it has evolved in the past few years. One can probably approximate something similar with memoir and margin notes, although the large paper formats used by the OUP leave significantly more room for figures than, e.g., A4.

Answer (score 23):

**Edit (2):** With egreg's recent suggestion, the package is finally up on [**CTAN**](https://ctan.org/pkg/notestex)!

---

I'd like to toss my hat in the ring. While it may not be the exact same as the OUP, I made [NotesTeX](https://github.com/Adhumunt/NotesTeX) to mimic the OUP's format. Here's how it looks
[image]
**Edit: Another Example**
[image]

I hope this helped!

Comment: Well, the result seems good, why don't you contribute the package to CTAN?

Comment: In fact, I just uploaded it to CTAN. Hopefully, it'll be up there soon.

Comment: Where can we find the source of your "Edit: Another Example" about Lie groups and algebras ? (I like the template)

Comment: Looks great! I tryed to use it with \usepackage[russian]{babel} and all nice fonts disappeared. Can you give any advice how to fix this problem?

Comment: Adding different languages has been a bit tricky. You will have to load both the babel package and the font package a second time in your .tex file. I'm still looking for global solutions.